# R Plotly - button is not updating with correct data (bar chart with color)

Tags: r, button, plotly, bar-chart

I am trying to add custom button to update the y axis, here is a small example that is similar.
When I click on “frq” or “count” the correct bar chart appears, but the values are wrong (its take only one value for each city and put it in all gender categories bars)

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Occupation = c("Tel Aviv", "Paris", "Amsterdam", "Kyoto")
Gender = c("F", "M", "[missing]")

df <- crossing(Occupation, Gender) %>%
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(.data[["Occupation"]]) %>%
  mutate(frq = round(100 * (n / sum(n)), 1))


chart_type <- list(
  type = "buttons",
  direction = "right",
  xanchor = 'center',
  yanchor = "top",
  pad = list('r' = 0, 't' = 10, 'b' = 10),
  x = 0.1,
  y = 1.20,
  buttons = list(
    list(
      method = "update",
      args = list(list(y = list(df$n))),
      label = "count"
    ),
    list(
      method = "update",
      args = list(list(y = list(df$frq))),
      label = "frq"
    )
  )
)

df %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~ Occupation,
    y = ~ n,
    color = ~ Gender,
    text =  ~ n,
    textposition = 'auto',
    type = "bar"
  ) %>%
  layout(updatemenus = list(chart_type))
```

Another version:

```
chart_type <- list(
  type = "buttons",
  direction = "right",
  xanchor = 'center',
  yanchor = "top",
  pad = list('r'= 0, 't'= 10, 'b' = 10),
  x = 0.1,
  y = 1.20,
  buttons = list(
    list(method = "update",
         args = list(list(visible = c(TRUE, FALSE)
                          )),
         label = "count"),
    list(method = "update",
         args = list(list(visible = c(FALSE, TRUE)
                          )), 
         label = "frq")
  ))

df %>% 
  plot_ly(mode = 'markers',type = "bar") %>%
    add_trace(x = ~Occupation, y = ~n, color = ~Gender,
        text=~n, textposition = 'auto', visible = FALSE,
        colorbar = list()) %>%
    add_trace(x = ~Occupation, y = ~frq, color = ~Gender,
            text=~frq, textposition = 'auto', visible = TRUE,
            colorbar = list()) %>%

  layout(updatemenus = list(chart_type))
```

[image: The image of the bar chart can be found here]

After the click:

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please add a simple sentence before the code which gives a summary about what the code for, something like "I use de following code to create the chart:". Could you also change the link text below to "Example chart" or something that makes sense? Good luck.

Comment: Your code isn't reproducible: `object 'x' not found`

Comment: Thanks @ismirsehregal- just fix it

Comment: It seems like "update" method is not compatible with color mapper from plotly...